# Is “evictable” an acceptable adjectival form of ‘evict’?

Tags: adjectives, computing, derivational-morphology

Is it correct to use "*evictable*" as an adjective for something that can be evicted?

**I plan to use the term in computer science context** as an adjective on a cache whose entries can be evicted to illustrate the contrast between an implementation, where you can evict any individual entry from the cache as opposed to an implementation where you cannot evict individual entries, but have to destroy the cache.

Every text editor highlights it as an incorrect, but people understand its meaning. Is there a synonym or another spelling?

Comment: Generally it's a person or a family that gets evicted. One doesn't evict a house or a building or a file; one empties them, I suppose, but it's people that get the attention (and special words).

Comment: If "evict" is the jargon term used in your technology, I see nothing wrong with "evictable".

Comment: @JohnLawler, you can think of a cache as a house and entries in the cache as residents. So you can rephrase my question as how do I denote residents that can be evicted.

Comment: Why choose something as restrictive with its object as "evict" rather than "eject" or "exclude" or "reject"?

Comment: If you want to distinguish between caches where individual entries can be emptied/cleared and those where you must clear the entire thing at once, then it would be better to characterise on that basis (eg piecewise vs indivisible) rather than evictable vs non-evictable. Eviction can refer to expelling one or many people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you describe the problem, it is the entries that are to be *evictable* (or *deletable*), rather than the cache, which will still remain after the eviction of an entry. This means you have a choice: extend the meaning of *evictable* to apply to the container from which things are evicted; or retain *evictable* (*deletable*) for the things and find another word (*emptiable*?) to describe the container.

The application of language to new circumstances, such as arise when developing new technology, sometimes demands new words or the extension of the meaning of old words. Text editors are therefore unreliable guides to what is acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

The verb to evict or any of its derivatives are inappropriate for the meaning that you intend.

To evict is solely transitive and solely refers to **persons** being removed from a property.

The past participle, as an adjective, always implies the passive: The **evicted** tenants = The tenants who **have been evicted**.

OED:

> **Evict (v.) 2.** *transitive*. Sometimes with of, from, out of.
>
> **a. To expel (a person) by legal process from land, property, etc., occupied by him or her. Now esp. to eject (a tenant) from his or her holding.**
>
> 2008   A. Bryant Compl. Guide to Prop. Investing Success viii. 199   *If the tenant still does not leave the property..you will have to apply via the Court for a bailiff to evict them.*

It is not possible to evict a property or a place. It is therefore not possible to have "evictable" refer to a property - "evictable" is only applicable to its tenants/occupants.

Added:

I suggest that the verb you want is simply "remove".

Comment: Words constantly take on new meanings as English evolves.  It's perfectly permissible to extend the meaning of evict, especially if nothing better exists to convey his concept.